# TypeScript migration: Simplest fix for JavaScript style const definitions generating errors?

Tags: typescript

I'm experimenting with migrating a moderately large project from JavaScript to TypeScript by renaming `.js` file to `.ts`.  The project is large, I'm starting with small examples.   The JavaScript code is already class like, and I've chosen a simple class `Token` class with no dependencies to start with.   A simplified version appears below, the bottom line of which generates an error using tsc 1.8 saying **"Property 'INVALID_TYPE' does not exist on type () => any."**

```
function Token() {
    this.source = null;
    this.type = null; // token type of the token
    this.line = null; // line=1..n of the 1st character
    this.column = null; // beginning of the line at which it occurs, 0..n-1
    return this;
}

Token.INVALID_TYPE = 0;
```

I understand how, by converting `function Token` into a `class Token`, I can make `INVALID_TYPE` a static member of class `Token`, but doing this across nearly 10k lines of code becomes rather complex.   I'm looking for a more incremental approach.  One simpler approach to eliminating the errors is to change the last line to:

```
(<any>Token).INVALID_TYPE = 0;
```

Is there better quick-fix to temporarily eliminate this kind of TypeScript error message?

Comment: a really quick fix would be something like `const Token = <any> function() {...` instead of the function declaration.

Comment: Thank you @BenSouthgate, very cool.   How do I deal with a class/function which is a subclass of `Token`

Comment: Retract that, I misread an error message.   Thank you.

Comment: @BenSouthgate, if you answer using the PostYourAnswer button (rather than as a comment), you'll get credit for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to rewrite the function declaration as a function expression (make sure there are no issues from the loss of hoisting!) and cast it to the `any` type, you can then add whatever props you want.

```
const Token = <any> function() {
  // ...
}
```